# Functions, Procedure & Triggers - how are they different, and when to use?

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I am very new to Oracle PL/SQL...

What is the difference between Oracle Functions, Procedure & Triggers? And what are appropriate uses of each?

Comment: Procedures doesn't return any values their just get parameters and do something with them, functions does the same by their also can return you a value based on their work. Triggers are kind of event handlers that react on any action you want and start procedure when this action happens. For example, you can create trigger on select on some table, and when someone does select from this table you can write about this action in some log table.

Comment: @stee thanks..Suppose i am inserting 100 rows in table A and want to write trigger which will manupulate and  insert these data(100 rows of table A)into Table B ..Is it possible and how...i m using Oracle 9i PL/SQL.....and thanks a lot your info was very helpfull..

Comment: You can read about trigger creation in oracle docs: `http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm`. It's really simple and clear there, i think. If you'll have any questions after or while reading, u can ask here and i'll try to answer. And, btw, triggers are not very popular, because they're taking a lot of database resources, especially triggers with logic that you described in previous message.

Comment: @see1rat, why don't you post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Functions and Procedures:
  basically just a piece of code that you run at will. In any language Function will return a value (eg' number of rows updated, a string etc') and a Procedure will not return any value.
- Triggers: Are pieces of code that run because of an event; For example you have a table and you would like that after every insert to this table, you will get an email - Then you define an AFTER INSERT trigger ON myImportant table and tell it to send you an email with the contents of the recent Insert.

A trigger can and probably will use functions and procedures.

Answer (score 2):

All three are different types of PL/SQL Blocks, which means that you can group multiple SQL statements and use variables, exception blocks so on. Procedures and functions in particular help re-use, so that you don't have to write the same logic at multiple places and you can grant someone/some application access to "do something" or "get some value" but not access the tables directly.

It is probably better to explain the difference with different use cases.
Let's consider the simple case of a customer placing an order.

Every order that is placed will have a series of steps, so you can have a **PL/SQL Block that does that work (executes a set of sql statements)**. A procedure is the way to implement this.

```
/* this is usually part of a package and not a stand-alone procedure, 
   but everything else holds good */

create or replace procedure p_create_order(
      i_product_id in products.product_type,
      i_price in orders.price%type,
      i_shipping_method in 
      i_state in address.state%type)
as
begin

  insert into orders(item_id, 
                     product_price, 
                     tax_and_other_charges) 
        values (i_product_id, 
                i_price,
                f_get_tax(i_price, i_state));   **---function call**

  update inventory set quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand - 1;

  insert into shipping_request(....) values(....) 

  commit;
end;
/
```

Let's assume the total tax calculation is based on series of conditions, you can (and should) avoid coding the logic at multiple places by calling a function instead. A function  can return only one value, which is what you need in most cases. If you need more than one value to be returned, you can use a procedure and out parameters.

```
create or replace function f_get_price(
               i_price in product.price%type,
               i_state in address.state%type)
   return number
as
  o_total_price number;
begin
  select i_price *tax_per percent
     into o_total_price
     from state_tax
     where state = i_state; 

  if(...some condition..)
    then  o_total_price = o_total_price*0.8
  else...
    ...
  end if;

  return o_total_price;

end;
/
```

Triggers are used for a completely different reason. If you want to execute a set of statements when some condition is met (triggering event), trigger **might be** your solution.

You can read more about their use cases in the link below. Please note that more often than not, there is an oracle feature (like auditing, versioning) etc, which is already in place so that you don't have to re implement it using triggers. Make sure you research before developing a solution, particularly using triggers.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#i1006211